# Background image paths won't render correctly

Tags: css, django, background-image, less

I'm using Django Compress to be able to use less files directly, instead of having to convert them to css files, which works fine except for the background images which paths doesn't get translated correctly, by some reason.

The less files is linked in to base.html like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" media="all" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/less/style.less" />
```

The images lives in *static/images* and the less files in *static/css/less*. In the less files I link to them like this:

```
background-image:url(".../images/sprite.png");
```

...which should work fine, but isn't working at all. When looking at the rendered css the background images paths is:

```
"http://localhost:8000/static/css/less/.../images/sprite.png"
```

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

**NOTE:** I've tried 1, 2 and 3 dots without any luck.

Comment: What if you use ../../images/a.png

Comment: why do you use 3 dots? use 2 instead. will that work?

Comment: I've tried 1, 2 and 3 dots... None will work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your images are in static folder you have to go back two directory:

```
backgroun-image: url('../../images/sprite.png');
```

Answer (score 1):

your path looks not right.Your css can't find the path of the path,you can check the path and test it!

try to use the 2

```
background-image:url("../images/sprite.png") no-repeat;
background:1px solid red;
```

to see there is something exits or not

Answer (score 0):

Three dots instead of two. Fix that.

```
background-image:url("../images/sprite.png");
```

Comment: Okay, I think the image path is wrong. Please try "../../images/sprite.png"